# Файловый вывод и endl в c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
        std::ofstream oo{"qwer.h"};

        oo << "hello 1"  << std::endl;

        std::ifstream ff{"qwer.h"};

        std::string ss;
        while(ff)
        {
                ff >> ss;

                if(ff.eof())
                        break;
                std::cout << ss << std::endl;;
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Результат:

```
hello
1
```

Но если я поменяю `oo << "hello 1"  << std::endl;` на `oo << "hello 1"  << '\n';` или `oo << "hello 1";`, то ничего не выведется. Вопрос почему ?

P.S
Знаю, что может помочь `oo << "hello 1"  << std::flush;`, но во-первых так выводится только `hello`, во вторых если бы строка выглядела бы так `oo << "hello"  << std::flush;` (единица отсутствует),то точно так же никакого вывода не было бы, а в третьих всё равно не понимаю почему вышеприведенные варианты не работают.

Comment: `oo.flush();`, помимо этого переместите указатель в начало файла. std::endl сам его вызывает.

Comment: @こきん, оформите, пожалуйста, в виде ответа

Comment: @こきん `oo << "hello 1"  << std::flush;` данная строка выведет только `hello`

Comment: @VanechikSpace, ??? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush